# Posting Forms Using Sitecore through javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, post, sitecore

I am currently using Sitecore and I am trying to create a POST action to post info to a payment site using information gathered by the form. Knowing that Sitecore strips  tags from html makes it a bit of a pain. After some searching I found that I can use javascript to create a dynamic form and send that would be the answer my question, sadly I am a javscript newbie and while I was able to decipher the javacript I can't make it post.

Any input or links to basic info would be much appreciated.

Here is what my form code looks like:

```
<fieldset id="PayForm" > <br>
<!--Store Settings-->
<input type="Hidden" name="ps_store_id" value="******" />
<input type="Hidden" name="hpp_key" value="*******" />
<input type="Hidden" name="charge_total" value="40.00" />
<!--Item Details-->
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="quantity1" />
<input type="hidden" value="Public Speaking" name="description1" />
<select name="id1">
<option>Select Date...</option>
<option value="Sep22PubSp"> Sept-22
</option>
<option value="Sep29PubSp"> Sept-29
</option>
<option value="Nov19PubSp"> Nov- 19
</option>
</select>
<br />
<input type="hidden" value="40" name="price1" />
<!--Student Details-->
First Name<input type="text" name="ship_first_name" value="First Name" />  Last Name  <input type="text" name="ship_last_name" value="Last Name" /> <br />
Student ID#: <input type="text" name="cust_id" value="Student ID" /><br />
Email<input type="text" name="email" value="Email" /> <br />
CCID<input type="text" name="note" value="CCID" /><br />
</fieldset>
```

And here is what my Javascript looks like

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
function post_to_url() {

    // The rest of this code assumes you are not using a library.
    // It can be made less wordy if you use one.
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute("method", "post");
    form.setAttribute("action", "******WEBSITE HERE*******");
    form.setAttribute("target", "tfl");

    var fieldset = document.getElementById("PayForm");
    var copy = fieldset.cloneNode(true);

    var description1 = document.getElementById("type_description1_form");
    var ship_first_name = document.getElementById("type_ship_first_name_form");
var ship_last_name = document.getElementById("type_ship_last_name_form");
var cust_id = document.getElementById("cust_id");
var email = document.getElementById("type_email_form");
var note = document.getElementById("type_note_form");

    var description1Input = document.createElement("input");
    description1Input.setAttribute("name", "type_description1");
    description1Input.setAttribute("value", description1.options[description1.selectedIndex].value);

    var ship_first_nameInput = document.createElement("input");
    destinInput.setAttribute("name", "type_ship_first_name");
    destinInput.setAttribute("value", ship_first_name.options[ship_first_name.selectedIndex].value);

    var ship_last_nameInput = document.createElement("input");
    ship_last_nameInput.setAttribute("name", "type_ship_last_name");
    ship_last_nameInput.setAttribute("value", ship_last_name.options[ship_last_name.selectedIndex].value);

    var cust_idInput = document.createElement("input");
    cust_idInput.setAttribute("name", "type_cust_id");
    cust_idInput.setAttribute("value", cust_id.options[cust_id.selectedIndex].value);

    var emailInput = document.createElement("input");
    emailInput.setAttribute("name", "type_email");
    emailInput.setAttribute("value", email.options[email.selectedIndex].value);

    var noteInput = document.createElement("input");
    noteInput.setAttribute("name", "type_note");
    noteInput.setAttribute("value", note.options[note.selectedIndex].value);


    form.appendChild(copy);
    form.appendChild(originInput);
    form.appendChild(destinInput);

    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
};
// ]]></script>
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Not necessarily related, but there is no reason that you shouldn't be able to do this in a Sitecore template. Are you trying to set this form up using their WYSIWYG editor? You don't appear to be interacting with any sitecore elements, so consider creating this as a component (.ascx control) and adding that as a template in sitecore.

Answer (score 5):

Your issue here is not that Sitecore strips form tags. Your issue is that you are working in ASP.Net webforms, which require special considerations for forms. This is because you already have a form tag, with the attribute runat="server" working to display sitecore's components.

That said, your javascript as it is written will never work in sitecore's environment. You simply can't nest an html form inside of an ASP.Net webform.

See this article on the basics of modifying your ASP.net template to support form submission:
http://www.sitepoint.com/net-form-processing-basics/
Alternatively, you could create the form as you expect it to work (again, without javascript) as pure html, and include it in a sitecore component template (.ascx control) in an IFrame.